# Cancan - can't save data for other roles - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, cancan

can you help my to fix my problem. I can save data if the user is `managing partner` but when I choose other roles, (like `secretary`), I can't save data to the database.

I think, there's a problem here. This is my codes:

```
def profile

        @office = Office.last
        @partial = (params[:type].present?) ? params[:type] : "work_data"

        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @user.is_managing_partner = true if current_user.role == 'managing partner'
    end

    def update_profile
        @office = Office.last
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @user.is_managing_partner = true

        if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
            flash[:success] = "Profile updated"

            case params[:type]
            when 'work_data'
                redirect_to profile_user_path(type: "personal_data")
            when 'personal_data'
                redirect_to root_path
            end

        else
            @partial = (params[:type].present?) ? params[:type] : "work_data"
            render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
    end
```

and this is my application_controller.rb

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  @office = Office.last
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user == current_user
      @partial = (params[:type].present?) ? params[:type] : "work_data"
      authorize! :read, @user
      render 'profile'
    else
      flash[:warning] = "Access Denied."
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
```

and this is my ability.rb

```
if user.role == 'managing partner'
  can :manage, :all
else
  if user.role == "secretary"
    can :update, :user_id => user.id
  end
  can :read, :all
end
```

Comment: CanCan is abandoned. Use CanCanCan instead (a drop-in replacement).

Answer (score 0):

In your ability.rb the 'can :update, :user_id => user.id' row is wrong. You have to specify WHAT he can update:

can :update, WHAT, :user_id => user.id